# puts within method in rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

my_file_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'my_file'

module M
  describe C do
    it 'should print everything' do
      c = C.new
      c.meth.should == "something"
    end
  end
end
```

my_file.rb:

```
module M
  class C
    puts "class TEXT" # label1
    def meth
     puts "method TEXT" # label2
     return "something"
    end
  end
end
```

The output is:

```
class TEXT

M::C
  should print everything

Finished in 0.75 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

And finally the question: "Why wasn't the `label2` -- ("method TEXT") printed after the test had been run?"

P.S.
Ruby192, rspec2

Comment: Have just tried it. "method TEXT" *was* printed in my case.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try using `$stderr.puts "method TEXT"`. This works for me. Just be aware that it is considered bad practice to write tests that have output that you need to examine manually, but I guess you already know that...

Comment: Yes, that works. But none of `puts`, `logger.error` etc. do not. And i would like to find out the reason if possible within my example.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with stdout being buffered in most OS. If this guess is right, then adding $stdout.flush after the line you want to get the output of should help.

Comment: Nope, buffering isn't the reason